# ForgeAPI Viewer for 2D to have a rotate button on the Viewer toolbar

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is it possible that we can have a rotate button on the viewer toolbar shown here? [ForgeAPI Viewer Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hkss.png)

Answer (score 0):

To rotate sheets in Viewer, you can take a look at this post : [Rotate Sheets Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/rotate-sheets-viewer)

Then, if you want to create a button for this, you can follow the viewer documentation : [Customize toolbar](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/developers_guide/viewer_basics/toolbar-button/)